# Membership and role provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone let me know where email address is stored in the mvc database for a new installation.

For example if I get a user from:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
```

and then look at the property user.email this is null. I cant seem to see a flag in the database anywhere for where this is set.

I can save this value to the userprofile table like this

```
String confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new {Email=model.Email}, requireEmailConfirmation);
```

Answer (score 0):

The email and any other user information is stored in the `UserProfile` table. If you want to use the simple membership provider that comes with ASP.NET MVC 4, you should no longer use the `Membership.GetUser` method but you should directly query your database using the corresponding DBContext. Take a look at the [following article](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/) which describes how custom properties could be added to the user profile.

Comment: so i should use    Profile profile = db.Profiles.Where(i => i.Username == userName).FirstOrDefault(); why does getuser function not return the email address